# Get the iPhone contacts using Objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried to get the contacts from the iPhone . I have used this [link](http://sugartin.info/2011/09/07/get-information-from-iphone-address-book-in-contacts/) it is working in simulator but not working on device . Please tell me . The issue is it is giving an empty array .

Comment: Not working _how_? What problem are you seeing? Have you allowed/declined your app to access the contacts?

Comment: Did you autorised the app to get these info (since iOS 6 I think, in the Settings of the phone)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Larme the issue is after installing it is not showing in the setting->privacy->contacts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you request the access to your contacts in your app?

To do that you have to add the following code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
           // add the contact
    }
```